# Is there a way to change attributes in runtime using postsharp?

Tags: c#, attributes, translation, postsharp

What i am trying to do, is to translate an application that uses attributes to set text in controls. I was thinking about custom reources manager but attributes has to be hardcoded.
My question is:

Is there any way to change visible text set by an attribute using PostSharp and where are the attributes stored in runtime?

e.g. for code

```
[DataMember]
[DisplayName("Mission description")]
[Description("Description of this mission")]
public string Description { get; set; }
```

What do i want to achive is to extract "Mission description" and "Description of this mission" to external file, translate it, and pass new translated values to Description String as an Attribute during execution of program.

Comment: Could you complete your question with an example of the code you wish you would be able to write, and a description of the desired effect of that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i had to do was to create a class that inherits from System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute, name it "DisplayNameAttribute" to override parent class, and overwrite parent class constructor, "DisplayName" and "DisplayNameValue" properties.
Next I put my logic into DisplayNameValue getter.
Then create DescriptionAttribute class by analogy.

```
public class DisplayNameAttribute : System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttributes
{
        private string name;

        public DisplayNameAttribute() { }
        public DisplayNameAttribute(String name) { this.name = name; }

        public override string DisplayName 
        { 
            get 
            { 
                return DisplayNameValue;
            } 
        }

        public string DisplayNameValue
        {
            get
            {
                /* e.g logic for reading from dictionary file */
                return myDictionary[name];
            }
            set
            {
                name = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where "string name" is where i hold my key to Dictionary.